# Is it possible to use cantilever brake pads with caliper brakes?

Tags: brakes, compatibility

Pretty much what the title says. I have an unused set of threaded post brake pads designed for V-/cantilever brake mechanisms (DIN EN 14766 if you're curious). Can I safely use these in a more modern caliper system?

Comment: If the mounting scheme is compatible, and the pads are not too thick or thin to work with the new brake, and the shape of the pads works with the rim, then they should work.  The other issue is how much pressure the pads need to be effective, but this varies a lot even between similar brake designs.

Comment: (The real problem is going the other way, as cantis need  a pad with a longer stem and those funny washers in order to be adjustable to meet the rim straight.)

Comment: My primary concern is structural integrity of the pad. Because cantis hinge with upward force and calipers come from above, are they engineered with the specific forces in mind, or is it simply a rubber block on a bolt?

Comment: Why take a risk ?  Brake pads are cheap - brakes are critical!   Get some quality brake pads with cartridge holders, and in the future you only need to swap the pad part.  Don't cut corners on your brakes.

Comment: Agreed. That's the route I decided to go. Thanks team